# iPhone - app which can not be killed

Tags: iphone

I am trying to understand, is there any way to develop iPhone app with following conditions:

1) This application should always run in the background

2) This application should not be killable

3) With out JailBreak?

All I am trying to do is want to track my iPhone.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer is NO. you cannot do that. Apple won't allow it.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear exactly what you want to do, but one of the cases where Apple allows apps to run in the background is so that they can respond to changes in the GPS location. It's not unkillable *per se*, but apps do relaunch automatically (I think) if they're killed due to low memory, etc.

See [here for the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible unless you are Apple.

Answer (score 1):

No. I'm pretty sure attempting this is going to get your app rejected (if its even possible!). The iOS system has its own ways of managing running applications and will kill apps if certain conditions are met (e.g. unresponsive for a while).

Check out the [App State & Multitasking doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. I saw applications like iPhone own apps like Photos, Phone etc which are not deletable so thought if I could make an app like that, will run always.

Comment: Those are system apps which come in-built, buddy. Only Apple can make that happen :) They have not provided access to developers for this kind of functionality. Bottom line - I'm certain what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: @Madhu: I think you should refer to this question on Meta-Stackoverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts as you use words like `buddy` too often which is of no use. Also in your answer you should use proper english words rather than slang english words.   Nothing personal.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are:

> 1) This application should always run in the background
>
> 2) This application should not be killable
>
> 3) With out JailBreak?

**Answer:**

I think there is no Non-Apple app which has all the three features. I think even one of these feature is nearly not possible.

Also if you say that Photos and Phone and others like Newsstand cannot be deleted, then you need to consider that those are apps of Apple and they have some more capabilities than what  they give in Public API's to the developers.

They have some greater access to the iOS and many of its private API's which make them non-deletable.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to release it to AppStore, but rather will sign with enterprise distribution certificate and will use it in your enterprise then you can look at VOIP application for iOS. It runs in the background, system restarts it automatically. I think that's the closest you can get on non jailbroken device.